# How to count number of days in a date range which satisfy some condition using pandas in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, date

I currently have a pandas dataframe where each row has a date range, and I want to count the number of days within this range that match some criteria:

```
Item | Date Start | Date End
----------------------
A    | 02/01/2019 | 03/02/2019
B    | 04/02/2019 | 08/02/2019
```

For example: The number of days in the range that fall within January-2019 or the number of days in the range in 2019:

```
Item | Date Start | Date End    | Days in Jan-2019 | Days in 2019 | Days in Q1 - 2019
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A    | 02/01/2019 | 03/02/2019  | 30               | 33           | 33
B    | 04/04/2019 | 08/04/2019  | 0                | 5            | 0
```

Ideally I don't want to have to create a row for every date in the range to make this calculation, and could leave the row structure as-is, but can't work out how to do this, or what the most efficient way would be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is necessary create ranges for each pairs and if only few conditions is possible use `sum` with conditions:

```
df['Date Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Start'], dayfirst=True)
df['Date End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date End'], dayfirst=True)

s = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Date Start'], x['Date End']), axis=1)
df['Days in Jan-2019'] = s.apply(lambda x: ((x.year == 2019) & (x.month == 1)).sum())
df['Days in 2019'] = s.apply(lambda x: (x.year == 2019).sum())
df['Days in Q1 2019'] = s.apply(lambda x: ((x.year == 2019) & (x.quarter == 1)).sum())

print (df)
  Item Date Start   Date End  Days in Jan-2019  Days in 2019  Days in Q1 2019
0    A 2019-01-02 2019-02-03                30            33               33
1    B 2019-02-04 2019-02-08                 0             5                5
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for flatten date ranges and thn aggregate `sum` by level values:

```
df['Date Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Start'], dayfirst=True)
df['Date End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date End'], dayfirst=True)

df['r'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Date Start'], x['Date End']), axis=1)
df1 = df.explode('r')
df1['Days in Jan-2019'] = (df1['r'].dt.year == 2019) & (df1['r'].dt.month == 1)
df1['Days in 2019'] =     df1['r'].dt.year == 2019
df1['Days in Q1 2019'] = (df1['r'].dt.year == 2019) & (df1['r'].dt.quarter == 1)

df = df.drop('r', axis=1).join(df1.sum(level=0))
print (df)
  Item Date Start   Date End  Days in Jan-2019  Days in 2019  Days in Q1 2019
0    A 2019-01-02 2019-02-03                30            33               33
1    B 2019-02-04 2019-02-08                 0             5                5
```